# Copying data between two different tables

Tags: mysql, database, stored-procedures, phpmyadmin

I have two tables, with different attributes. I am trying to copy some data from one table to another, but the problem is the other table has many default values set, so my stored procedure does not run saying, some field requires default value. Is there a way around this?

I have put my stored procedure, and it is giving me problems because of default values for the fields not present in the destination table.

```
DELIMITER $$
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS copy$$
CREATE PROCEDURE copy()
BEGIN
INSERT INTO `Beneficiaries` (`ACO_ID`,`Patient_First_Name`,`Patient_Last_Name`, `Status`, `Other_ID`) 
SELECT `ID`,`FName`,`LName`,`2016AttStatus`,`CCDID` FROM `Demographics`;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Any suggestions on automatically inserting defualt values in the Beneficiaries tbale would be highly appreciated.

Comment: which "other table"? the one you're selecting from, or the one you're inserting into?

Comment: The one I am inserting into, the 'Demographics' table, it has other fields which need default values.

Comment: The default value should be inserted when you dont include it on the insert statement, show db schema and sample data.

Comment: but I don't want to populate other fields besides the ones that I have mentioned above

Comment: There are some fields in the destination table, that are asking for default values, although i dont care what their values are or would be, I am just concerned with storing the values I want into the destination table